# Angular 4 application npm update gives "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 154871" error

Tags: angular

Somehow something broken in my angular 4 website.

I can not start(ng serve), install(npm install), update(npm update), uninstall anything at all.

Whatever I try I'm getting this error.
Unexpected token / in JSON at position 154871

I also tried npm cache verify.

Any idea would be appreciated. I believe one of the json config files broken but I couldn't find anything. Any advice please?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder in your project and reinstalling everything?  That often fixes the problem for me after an update.

Comment: Yes I also tried that. I think this is not related with the modules but maybe config files.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your package.json is malformed. Check it for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

+1
this is not just about deleting node_modules in an existing project, it fails to create new projects, same error on:
ng new my-app